# Openstack Swift stat [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: swift, openstack

When I type

```
swift stat
```

I get this error:

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='controller', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/AUTH_d17698cf7bbf4dcc8fc59ed6f7b48052 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1c597f9910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Comment: Serverfault has two duplicates of this question from the same user: Older https://serverfault.com/questions/1051039/connection-refused-errno-111-when-typing-swift-start-command and more recent https://serverfault.com/questions/1054485/openstack-swift-stat-errno-111-connection-refused.

Comment: both of these are posted by me and i still haven't found a solution